# Are Promises unicast or broadcast?

Tags: javascript, promise, frp

This [book](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/bridging_to_promises.html) says Promises are unicast, while this [one](https://github.com/kriskowal/gtor) says they are broadcast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence

> With Observable sequences, you get that behavior for free in a multicast behavior, instead of the unicast Promise behavior.

is inaccurate. It *seems* to refer to the fact that an observable can fire a callback multiple time while a promise fires its callbacks only (at most) once. However, that's not the standard meaning of [unicast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicast)/[broadcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast), which is about the number of receivers - of which both promises and observables can have any.

Comment: That makes more sense.

Comment: I wonder if the confusion comes from how a promise fires only once, while it's result can be repeatedly retrieved by `p.then()` callback?

Answer (score -1):

They are immutable memoized values. So they go both ways if needed.